# LG External CD/DVD Drive not recognized 16.04

Tags: 16.04, usb-drive

I recently upgraded to 16.04 and cannot get Ubuntu to recognize my external cd/dvd drive.  It powers up, opens and closes with no problems, but does not mount.  The output for sudo lshw -short is below, and I don't see it even showing up here.

```
H/W path        Device           Class          Description
===========================================================
                                 system         Computer
/0                               bus            Motherboard
/0/0                             memory         31GiB System memory
/0/1                             processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4440 CPU @ 3.10GHz
/0/100                           bridge         4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller
/0/100/1                         bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor P
/0/100/1/0                       display        GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti]
/0/100/1/0.1                     multimedia     NVIDIA Corporation
/0/100/14                        bus            8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB 
/0/100/14/0     usb4             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/1     usb3             bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/1/4   wlx9cefd5ff238e  network        802.11 n WLAN
/0/100/14/1/5                    input          USB Receiver
/0/100/14/1/8                    multimedia     HD Pro Webcam C920
/0/100/14/1/b                    input          USB Receiver
/0/100/16                        communication  8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI 
/0/100/1a                        bus            8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB 
/0/100/1a/1     usb1             bus            EHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1a/1/1                    bus            USB hub
/0/100/1b                        multimedia     8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Defini
/0/100/1c                        bridge         8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI 
/0/100/1c.2                      bridge         8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI 
/0/100/1c.2/0   eth0             network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Et
/0/100/1d                        bus            8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB 
/0/100/1d/1     usb2             bus            EHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1d/1/1                    bus            USB hub
/0/100/1f                        bridge         H87 Express LPC Controller
/0/100/1f.2                      storage        8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-po
/0/100/1f.3                      bus            8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBu
/0/2            scsi0            storage        
/0/2/0.0.0      /dev/sda         disk           512GB Crucial_CT512MX1
/0/2/0.0.0/1    /dev/sda1        volume         243MiB Linux filesystem partition
/0/2/0.0.0/2    /dev/sda2        volume         476GiB Extended partition
/0/2/0.0.0/2/5  /dev/sda5        volume         476GiB Linux LVM Physical Volume partiti
```